PCF8563 not answering ACK, is there something wrong with my circuit?
I have been developing a board with some I2C peripherals, one that is LSM6DS3 from ST answers the ACK just find, but I can’t get PCF8563 to answer as well.
Here is what I already did trying to solve this problem:

Mesured power rails (it’s feeding 3.3 volts to the IC just fine).
Removed the crystal and soldered it again.
Removed the LSM6DS3 and left just the PCF8563 on the I2C bus.
Resoldered the IC and it’s crystal.

My I2C bus has 4.7 K resistors as pull-up and everything is working at 3.3 V.
Here is the schematic I’m using:

Any suggestions on what I’m doing wrong ? I’m using an ESP32 with the default Arduino I2C scanner to check for the peripherals.
Edit:
Here is my layout:

Here is the datasheet of the crystal

Are you sure you are using the correct START condition and the correct slave address? Also, the IC is quite sensitive so a proper layout is needed. Check my question here for a similar problem.

@Rohat Kılıç It could be, but it´s not all that far from the SMD example. When you had your problem, could you talk to the IC ? right now i´m just scanning all addresses for an ACK but i get none.

Did you try it with 2.2 kohm pullup?

@Jens no, but i could try, why should it make a difference ?

@DMinatto - Hi, (a) Please [edit] the question and add photos of the actual PCB, other hardware & cabling. It's possible that site members might spot something relevant. (b) Please also add scope trace images (oscillograms) showing the I2C signals while trying to communicate with the PCF8563. Ensure the scope's reference (0V) level is shown and the horizontal & vertical scales are set so the quality of those signals to be reviewed e.g. rise/fall times, timing, voltage levels etc.

Show the PCB design and also maybe a photo of the board. Also the parameters of the crystal are unknown. Please post which crystal you bought, to see if it is compatible or not.

@DMinatto when we got the problem the communication was unstable, despite the fact that there was only the PCF8563T on the I2C line. I can't give an exact number but we had garbage once in maybe 5 queries. As mentioned in the question, we initially moved all the PCF8563T and related stuff onto a separate PCB. Anyway, you may have a layout issue. As others mentioned, please put photos of layout.

@DMinatto We don't know anything about the layout and I just wanted to exclude a bus capacitance issue with these stronger pullups. Soldering another 4k7 on top of the existing one for a test is quickly done.

@Jens, my bus is really short, gonna add  my layout on the post.

On your layout SDA and SCL are swapped at the RTC and I don't see a GND connection (pin 4).

@Jens, damn, you are right, thank you, GND is copper fill it will be connected once i do de filling.

OK, by the way, it would be interesting if this RTC can respond to I2C requests if it has no crystal. Would you mind to check this later?

@Jens i will give it a try, i´m curious too.

@Jens I Fixed the connections and it started showing up on the scanner. Removed the crystal and it was gone again, so at the end it really is dependent on the crystal for the internal clocking. Since it´s oscilating arround 32.9 Khz, and answering, i supose eaven if it´s off by a little bit it will still generate the clock pulses to run I2C. If you want to answer the post i will mark as the accepted answer.

Good, that you added a layout image.
Pin 5 and 6 of the RTC IC are swapped in the layout. Pin 5 is SDA and 6 is SCL.
The GND connection of pin 4 is not visible, but this may be because the filler is not displayed.
I know this effect very well, one stares at a layout for hours, but is blind for a very obvious detail.
I recommend, not to route I2C lines below a crystal pad. It may receive some extra edges and appear running faster.


Any suggestions on what I’m doing wrong ?

The OSCI input requires a capacitor to ground (usually a trimmer to calibrate the clock precisely) having a value between 5 pF and 25 pF: -

You can check whether your circuit is oscillating by looking at the waveform on CLKOUT (the default should be 32,768 Hz).
Image source. For the curious, if the oscillator is stopped, the device is resent and, during reset the \$I^2C\$ bus is not communicable with: -


There's also no evidence the chip's internal load capacitor is in the right range for the crystal used. It's probably suitable, but it's also possible a little additional load capacitance might be needed.

@Hearth that may be true or, it may not be true. What is true is that they should have at least 5 pF on the OSCI pin to GND.

I tryed adding a 5 pF capacitor and nothing has changed, still not found on the I2C bus. Gonna try to get an osciloscope to measure if it´s oscilating.

Does the I2C interface need a running crystal at all?

@Jens have you looked in the data sheet. There is a link in my answer. If you look on page 3 (the block diagram), the answer should be clear. Figure 10 is also quite useful. Additionally, the data sheet says this: The PCF8563 includes an internal reset circuit which is active whenever the oscillator is
stopped. In the reset state the I2C-bus logic is initialized including the address pointer and
all registers are set according to Table 27. I2C-bus communication is not possible during
reset.

@Andyaka OK, but I am not fully convinced, since it also states "the I2C-bus is asynchronous to the crystal oscillator" and it can respond during POR override. As I understand this, it will physically respond to the I2C bus, but not answer useful data during reset. At least this was the case with other I2C RTCs I have used.

@Jens take it up with the supplier is my advice. I'm only stating what the data sheet says and, they seem quite unambiguous about this = all I2C-bus communication is not possible in reset. The words came from the data sheet.

@Andyaka scoped the crystal and it´s oscilating arround 32.9 khz, do you think the frequency could be causing all the problems ?

@DMinatto my advice to you is read the data sheet on what the frequency limits are that prevent it producing a continuous reset. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
